# Find $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$, such that $\sqrt{\frac{m(m+1)}{n(n+1)}}$ is a rational number

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$, $m \neq n$, such that $N = \sqrt{\frac{m(m+1)}{n(n+1)}}$ is a rational number.

Comment: I don't know... what do you think?

Comment: Obviously I meant for $m \neq n$.

Comment: "Obviously?"  That's kind of condescending, don't you think?  How are we supposed to have inferred that if you didn't see fit to specify?  Also, while your efforts to edit your question to address @Michael's comment are commendable, you still haven't actually asked a question that is appropriate for MSE.  What do you think the answer is?  Why?  What have you done to attempt to answer?  What body of theory are you trying to use to solve the problem?  Please provide some context...

Comment: [$(8 \cdot 9) / (1 \cdot 2) = \ldots$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_triangular_number)

Comment: I modified the answer. Hope it's better now. My apologies.

Comment: `n>1`: $\;(24 \cdot 25) / (2 \cdot 3) = \ldots$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are infinitely solutions because there are infinitely many [square triangular numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_triangular_number).

Just choose $m$ and $n$ from the sequence [OEIS/A001108](https://oeis.org/A001108):
$$
1,8,49,288,1681,9800,57121,332928,1940449,11309768,65918161,384199200,\dots
$$